# Generate SQL with Powershell & Regex

Tags: sql, regex, powershell

I have the following ddl(Data definition language) structure in sql:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
 key ...,
 key1 ...,
 u_version ...,
 field1 ...,
 field2 ...
)
CREATE UNIQUE clustered... (key ASC, key1 ASC)
```

Because I want to create multiple tables with **that structure**, only **the name of tables, keys and field names are different**. So I want to use Powershell script to scan every file in the directory and generate sql script for each file.
The generated script should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(key, key1, u_version, field1, field2)
SELECT key, key1, field1, field2
FROM tablename_temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT key, key1
                  FROM tablename l
                  WHERE l.key = t.key AND l.key1 = t.key1)
```

For tablename & table_name_tempdb, I use the following:

```
switch -Regex ( $line ) {

    '(^\s*create\s+table\s+)(?<tablename>[^(]*)' {                          
        $table_name = $matches["tablename"] 
        $table_name_tempdb="${table_name}_tmp"
        break
        }
    }
```

**Now I want to do the same to keys and other fields. Are there any suggestions?**

My idea is to scan every lines from the CREATE TABLE to ")" and add every word begins with " " and ends with " " in a list. Lines before u_version are keys, the others are considered as fields and build query with those.

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!\A),?\s*|^\s*create\s+table\s+[^(]*\()\s*(?<keys>\w+)\s+(?<values>.*?)(?=,$|\r?\n\)\r?\n)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/S9HFtE/1). You need to access the CaptureCollection of the `keys` and `values` groups to get all captured values. Make sure you are not passing one line to the regex, but the whole text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example, based upon the information provided, that outputs the new SQL.

I tweaked you SQL (your insert as is would have failed).  Also, if your input files differ from your example, the expression will need tweaking.

Reading content with -Raw allows the whole file to be parsed together.

```
dir *.sql  |%{
    $filecontents = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw

    $matches =  [Regex]::Match($filecontents, "CREATE TABLE (?'tablename'[^( ]+)\((\W+(?'key'\w+)\W(?'type'[^,)])+[,)])+(\W+u_version\W([^,)])+[,)])(\W+(?'field'\w+)\W(?'type'[^,)])+[,)])+\W+CREATE UNIQUE")

    $tablename = $matches.Groups["tablename"].Value
    $keys = $matches.Groups["key"].Captures.Value
    $fields = $matches.Groups["field"].Captures.Value


'=================================================================='
@"
INSERT INTO $tablename($($keys -join ','), u_version, $($fields -join ','))
SELECT $($keys -join ','), u_version, $($fields -join ',')
FROM $($tablename)_temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM $tablename l
                  WHERE $(($keys |% { "l.$_ = t.$_" }) -join ' AND ')) 
                 

"@

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can go further with this!